# Hanging at "POST git-receive-pack (chunked)"

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I will be honest, I know very little about the internals of git.

I have staged and commit a 40mb directory, but when I come to push...

```
$ git push --verbose --progress
Pushing to https://acron0@bitbucket.org/acron0/project.git
Password for 'https://acron0@bitbucket.org':
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
```

It's been like this for 20 minutes. I am assuming it's hanging but...is there anything I can do to find out why?

Comment: I have the same problem, same error message, sourcetree & github end up freezing and crashing. I tried the command suggested below and now it says something similar: "POST git-receive-pack ({Some 9 digit long number})"

Comment: I had to update my Git version 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30842134/284909

Comment: Always worth checking the [status page](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/) - I was unable to push a new repository just now and found BitBucket SSH was down…

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This is a bug in Git; when using HTTPS it will use chunked encoding for uploads above a certain size. Those do not work.

A trivial fix is to tell git to not chunk until some ridiculously large size value, such as:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: still hangs on windows in git v1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: Setting `postBuffer` didn't help me, either, but updating to the pre-release of Git for Windows did (per http://stackoverflow.com/a/30842134/2688)

Comment: @bdukes this should posted as a solution, not a comment

Comment: This error was because ngix was configured to reject large files, so instead of add a more large buffer, you should put it on a range that your server (in my case nix default config) accepts. ```git config http.postBuffer 5242```should being chunks of about 5k.

Comment: In my case I had to reduce the post buffer size to 5000 as noted by @tyoc213

Comment: By the way, the final "good" way should be to add the remote public keys of your user to gitlab so it is enabled to use SSH instead of HTTPS, so it can handle now large files (except if the server rejects them as policy like github I guess will be do in future/now).

Comment: BTW on a Mac I had to edit ~/.gitconfig manually, then just added in section `[http]` the line: `postBuffer = 524288000`

Comment: I've solved by reducing the size as tyoc213 said. Working with github...

Answer (score 22):

Probably your credentials. Use the git+ssh protocol instead of https.

Comment: Worked for me also. Any ideas why it won't work with the https protocol?

Comment: I'm trying to do this for github, but there is no git+ssh option.

Comment: I have followed TCP stream and it was Authorization error for my account.

Answer (score 12):

Using SourceTree to push to BitBucket I get this error once every few months. It turns out that I just have to wait an extra five minutes and it sorts itself out. It looks like it has hanged and the temptation is to just cancel and try again but maybe hang in there a bit longer. I know that this is answered already but my commits amounted to maybe a couple of hundred kb rather than the 40mb the original poster is talking about.

Comment: Same case for me. I cancelled the push in SourceTree and waited for like 5 mins, tried again and it worked.

Comment: same story here

Comment: I waited for about an hour (28mb commit) - nothing, absolutely nothing happened.

Comment: @seulberg1 There are other answers here, have you tried them?

Comment: Yes, I tried different git versions, embedded - non embedded, waiting, limiting the chunk size, made sure I was authenticated.... In the end, I was able to solve it by deleting the last remote commit and "re-commit" the removed and the actual commit in one big chunk. Unfortunately, in my environment, I cannot switch to SSH authentication.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some partners in misery, but my hang is indefinite. I dream of only 5-minute hangs. I've left it overnight. One difference is that my push is to Github, so the problem may lie with that service.

Comment: same here! I have 6 pictures, all around 20mb, wait about 8mins.

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), you will be able to set `http.postBuffer` to a really large number (i.e,  larger than `ulong` on some platforms).

See [commit 37ee680](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37ee680d9b90fe4c4fc5be4e14f17baf49f6ce59) (11 Apr 2017) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4c01f67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c01f67d9102942cc7f0a737de4c609a6ac1832e), 24 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### `http.postbuffer`: allow full range of `ssize_t` values

> Unfortunately, in order to push some large repos where a server does
> not support chunked encoding, the `http postbuffer` must sometimes
> exceed two gigabytes.
> On a 64-bit system, this is OK: we just malloc a larger buffer.
>
> This means that we need to use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE to set the
> buffer size.

---

As a result, with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021) which drops support for ancient versions of cURL library (pre 7.19.4):

See [commit 644de29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/644de29e220de7441e51a29bf512278b3de0bbe1), [commit 013c7e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/013c7e2b070f5b69d6585b0c18426a959f1bf739), [commit 1119a15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1119a15b5c8521e75c412a129cd6318285cac773) (30 Jul 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 8dda4cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8dda4cbdf258be05e7201ef5d6e9d532cacb9178), [commit 5db9d38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5db9d383590c37272a9f16464a66dfbd3a3c8aff) (30 Jul 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e48a623](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e48a623dea0c9170e4daa5e27e5bbc3f1ce84354), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`http`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1119a15b5c8521e75c412a129cd6318285cac773): drop support for curl < 7.11.1
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Drop support for this ancient version of curl and simplify the code by allowing us get rid of some "#ifdef"'s.
>
> Git will not build with vanilla curl older than 7.11.1 due our use of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` in [37ee680](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37ee680d9b90fe4c4fc5be4e14f17baf49f6ce59) ("`http.postbuffer`: allow full range of `ssize_t` values", 2017-04-11, Git v2.13.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c01f67d9102942cc7f0a737de4c609a6ac1832e)).
> This field was introduced in curl 7.11.1.
>
> We could solve these compilation problems with more `#ifdefs`, but it's not worth the trouble.
> Version 7.11.1 came out in March of 2004, over 17 years ago.
> Let's declare that too old and drop any existing `ifdefs` that go further back.
> One obvious benefit is that we'll have fewer conditional bits cluttering the code.
>
> This patch drops all `#ifdefs` that reference older versions (note that curl's preprocessor macros are in hex, so we're looking for 070b01, not 071101).

Answer (score 1):

If you found this site because of BitBucket failing with that error message, then check out the answers to this one:

- [how to use git extension with bitbucket repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053608/how-to-use-git-extension-with-bitbucket-repository)

Particularly the comment by [Nicholas Pickering](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270996/nicholas-pickering) and [Simon Tewsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216440/simon-tewsi) about exactly what part of the key needs to be pasted into the BitBucket dialog.

Answer (score 0):

On rare occasions, this happens when I use SourceTree to push. I've found that it's best to just hit cancel if you've been stuck, wait a minute or so, and then push again. Sometimes it could take 3-5 minutes, but most of the time it successfully pushes.