# Pushing to gitlab remote repo stays processing and never pushes

Tags: git, gitlab

Sometimes I try to make a push to my Gitlab repository it stays in the same point but never completes the process. I have to try and try so many times until it makes it. But lately, not even trying many times it pushes.

I use the following code to push:
`git push repo master`

Any idea what could be the reason?

This is the log, and it stays in that last line:

```
Enumerating objects: 899, done.
Counting objects: 100% (791/791), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (436/436), done.
Writing objects: 100% (670/670), 2.03 MiB | 1.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 670 (delta 437), reused 354 (delta 228), pack-reused 0
```

Comment: Are you on a `windows` computer by any chance?

Comment: Q: Please [Edit] your post and specify exactly how you're trying to "push".  Using Git bash/command line (e.g. `git push`)?  Have you tried `git push --verbose`, or `git push -v --dry-run`? Or is your Git client Tortoise Git, VSCode, or "something else"?  What is your host: Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: @MarceloPaco I am using Ubuntu 20

Comment: @paulsm4 I run `git push repo master`

Comment: @paulsm4 I just tryed the --verbose and the --dry-run and same result. Not even a message

Comment: I found a thread with the solution. It's apparently a Git bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790232/hanging-at-post-git-receive-pack-chunked