# GIT Origin Commands Not Working (Pull,Push,Clone,Fetch etc.)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've checked the question : `git push` — No output, nothing happens. That didnt resolved my issue. Please check the screen shots I attached. I configured the origin and all configurations correctly.

I'm trying to set up a repository for my project. I could init the git repository and could able to setup a workspace in my server using git add, commit commands. But when I try to push to a remote repository in bitbucket its not working. The main issue is I'm not getting any error message. Please see the below screen.

[image]

I tried to reset the branch and push again as I seen in some of the similar issues.

```
$mypc > git ls-remote https://hojaonline@bitbucket.org/pitstypo3/staging.git
$mypc > git push origin master
$mypc > git pull https://hojaonline@bitbucket.org/pitstypo3/staging.git master
$mypc > git pull origin master
$mypc > git fetch origin master
$mypc > git origin -v
git: 'origin' ist kein Git-Befehl. Siehe 'git --help'.
$mypc > git config --get remote.origin.url
https://hojaonline@bitbucket.org/pitstypo3/staging.git
$mypc > git remote show origin
```

git remote -v
Output Screen

[image]

Comment: Please also show us a (if possible) tree view of you .git directory. Maybe your are missing something important there.

Comment: Please check whether you have configured remote for your local repository correctly by `git remote -v`.

Comment: @gzh, I've attached the git directory structure and remote details.

Comment: @eyorther please see the attached screen in edited version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`git push\` -- No output, nothing happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545861/git-push-no-output-nothing-happens)

Comment: @gzh No I tried in local machine the repo is perfectly all right and there is a dev server there also it works. In the mentioned post the error looks same but the issues are different

Comment: It would be better to copy and paste the output here rather than post a screenshot.

Comment: Note that `git origin` is not a command, just as the error says. `origin` is a remote and can be used with commands such as `git push` and `git pull`. I'm not sure why these are not working, however. You should check the question linked by gzh above.