# Bitbucket with Git extensions - authentication problems

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-extensions

I created an empty Bitbucket repository and I want to clone that to my computer using Git Extensions

[image]

I followed by [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053608/how-to-use-git-extension-with-bitbucket-repository) steps (created and added public key and saved the private...).

[image]

When I'm trying to clone that empty repository I get the following problem:

[image]

**What else can I do?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go into the settings and create an SSH Key and then add that key to the repository on bitbucket.

1. In git extension go to `Tools > Putty > Generate or Import Key`
2. Click `Generate`
3. Move your mouse around the empty area until the progress bar goes away.
4. Copy the entire SSH key.
5. Click save public key and save it somewhere
6. Then in your bitbucket repo go to `Settings > Deployment Keys > Add Key` and copy paste the key you generated into the `Key` field and save.
7. In GitExtensions goto your repository and load the SSH key

Comment: Are you sure your repo is set to SSH and not HTTPS? What is the repo URL in your repository settings?

Comment: When I'm trying to clone Pageant always ask again for private key

Comment: Load the SSH key from the file you saved earlier

Answer (score 5):

I solved that issue:
The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053608/how-to-use-git-extension-with-bitbucket-repository) I posted was correct as well as **aaronmallen's** answer.
The problem caused because when I press the clone button on Bitbucket it gives you the whole command line `git clone git@bitbucket.org:myuser/my-project.git`
I tried to clone throw Git Extension UI where I needed only the URL (`git@bitbucket.org:myuser/my-project.git`).